# Im able to populate spinner but cant access it

Tags: android, list, spinner, adapter

```
public void editarEstadoSala(final Sala sala) {

        ArrayAdapter<Pelicula> adapter;

        CambiarDatosSalaWorker cambiarDatosSalaWorker = new CambiarDatosSalaWorker(this);
        cambiarDatosSalaWorker.execute();

        List<Pelicula> listaPelicula=cambiarDatosSalaWorker.getLista();

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(PortalAdmin.this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //////

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PortalAdmin.this);
        builder.setTitle("Rellena los datos");

        final EditText butacas = new EditText(PortalAdmin.this);
        final EditText precio = new EditText(PortalAdmin.this);
        final TextView pelicula = new TextView(PortalAdmin.this);
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(PortalAdmin.this);
        pelicula.setText("Pelicula seleccionada");

        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
        butacas.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        butacas.setHint("Numero butacas libres");
        precio.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        precio.setHint("Precio entrada");


        spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Pelicula>(PortalAdmin.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , listaPelicula);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                pelicula.setText(item);


            } // to close the onItemSelected
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(PortalAdmin.this,
                        "nada",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast.show();


            }
        });

        layout.addView(butacas);
        layout.addView(precio);
        layout.addView(pelicula);
        layout.addView(spinner);
        builder.setView(layout);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Subir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }
```

I just cant make any progress here, the spinner is populated (List, comes from another class) but i cant do nothing with that data, Log.e doesnt show nothing so my code doesnt reach the spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener.

Sorry for my english guys, im learning code and english and im pretty bad at both.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was here

```
CambiarDatosSalaWorker cambiarDatosSalaWorker = new CambiarDatosSalaWorker(this);
        cambiarDatosSalaWorker.execute();

        List<Pelicula> listaPelicula=cambiarDatosSalaWorker.getLista();
```

I was using my class "CambiarDatosSalaWorker" wrong and the code there was wrong too haha

Here is the class now,

```
public class CambiarDatosSalaWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Pelicula>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Pelicula> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String result = "";
        String line = "";
        List<Pelicula> lista = new ArrayList<>();


        String datosPelicula = "here is the url where I get the info about the movies in my database";


        try {
            URL url = new URL(datosPelicula);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            result = "";
            line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            int ndatos = result.split("-_-").length;


            //String id, String nombre, String genero, String sinopsis, String url_imagen
            for (int i = 0; i < ndatos; i++) {
                Pelicula p = new Pelicula(result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[0], result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[1], result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[2], result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[3], result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[4]);
                System.out.println("id " + result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[0]);
                System.out.println("nombre " + result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[1]);
                System.out.println("genero " + result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[2]);
                System.out.println("sinopsis " + result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[3]);
                System.out.println("url " + result.split("-_-")[i].split("-")[4]);
                lista.add(p);
            }

            return lista;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Pelicula> peliculas) {
        super.onPostExecute(peliculas);


    }


}
```

Now it returns a List, I dont need a variable and method getList (wrong way to use the class).

And in my Activity I change to this...

```
//code

List<Pelicula> listaPelicula = null;
        CambiarDatosSalaWorker cambiarDatosSalaWorker = new CambiarDatosSalaWorker();

        try {
            listaPelicula = cambiarDatosSalaWorker.execute().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//code
```

------ >     listaPelicula = cambiarDatosSalaWorker.execute().get();

Now my spinner works just fine.